# Is the function $f\colon x\to x^2$ one-one or onto or both on a set of rational numbers, real numbers and complex numbers?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

We can easily see that the function $f\colon x\to x^2$ is not one-one or onto on the set of integers. Though it is one-one if defined on the set of positive integers. I wanted to know if the function is one-one or onto or both on a set of rational numbers, real numbers and complex numbers?

Comment: Well, either be more specific on this set you look for, or else just take $\{0\}$. Besides, the set of positive integers is also a set of rational, real or complex numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly on the rationals $x\mapsto x^2$ is not one-to-one since $-2$ and $2$ are both mapped to $4$, it is also not onto because there is no rational number such that $x^2=-1$.

By this the function is also neither one-to-one nor onto the real numbers, and it therefore cannot be one-to-one over the complex numbers. However it is onto the complex numbers because every complex number has a square root, by the virtue of the complex numbers being an algebraically closed field.

On the other hand, if we only consider positive rationals then the function is one-to-one, although it is not onto because $\sqrt 2$ is not in the image; but on the positive real numbers the function is both one-to-one and onto.

Comment: You don't need to know that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed in order to deduce the existence of square roots.

Comment: @Harald: How else would you deduce that $x^2-t$ has a root for every $t$ in the field?

Comment: For example by writing a given complex number in polar form as $re^{i\theta}$. Then the square roots are $\pm\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$.

Comment: @Harald: But why is this a well-defined complex number? Not every field is an exponentially closed field.

Comment: But we're not talking about every field. This is all about $\mathbb{C}$, which is a very concrete object assuming you know a few things about the real numbers.

Comment: @Harald: But this is not true for $\mathbb R$, which is also a *very* concrete field which appears in the question, right?

Comment: Hmm. I'm afraid you lost me there. What is it that is not true of $\mathbb{R}$? (Besides, I think this discussion is too high level to be of any use to the person asking the question in the first place.)

Comment: @Harald: While every real number is $e^x$ for some $x$, it still does not imply that every real number has a root. In the complex numbers it holds because the complex numbers is an algebraically closed field. True, you don't need *all* that power for this, but you do need *some* algebraic closure for your argument to hold, even more so because you rely on a *very* analytic representation which need not be true for general fields; whereas generally speaking for any alg. closed field the function $x\mapsto x^2$ is surjective.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to follow your argument. I suspect we are just talking past each other, and effectively not communicating. So I'll bow out now. It's bedtime here anyhow, and my brain is turning to mush.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, so I'll interpret it as asking for a subset $S$ of the complex numbers such that $f(x)=x^2$ is defined, one-one, and onto as a function from $S$ to $S$.

First note that the empty set, the set containing only zero, the set containing only one, and the set containing only zero and one all work, and if $S$ works then the union of $S$ with any of those sets also works. So that's settled, and we can ignore zero and one from here on.

Here's another set that works: $$\dots,2^{1/8},2^{1/4},2^{1/2},2,2^2,2^4,2^8,\dots$$ Viewing this as a sequence, $f$ is just a shift one slot to the right, and clearly one-one and onto.

Now there's nothing special about 2 here; we could start with any complex number $a$ and do $$\dots,a^{1/8},a^{1/4},a^{1/2},a,a^2,a^4,a^8,\dots$$ although we have to make some choices as to how we define the numbers to the left of $a$ if $a$ is not a nonnegative real number. What's more, we can take the union of any number of these sets for different values of $a$ and get another set $S$ that works. And that's as general an answer as you're going to get.

Now if you want all the elements of $S$ to be rational, you're stuck with $\{\,0,1\,\}$ and subsets thereof, because if $S$ has anything else in it then if you take enough inverse images ("square roots") you're guaranteed to hit an irrational. If you want all the elements of $S$ to be real, take only non-negative values of $a$.